# Optimizing outcome with resource restrictions

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics

Is there a name/algorithm for this variant of optimization problem?

> Suppose we have some arbitrary sets of jobs, workers, and tools. The sizes of each are not necessarily the same. For each job, we're given which workers can complete it using a particular tool. Determine the max number of jobs that can be completed, such that a worker can be assigned to multiple jobs, but a tool can only be used by one worker.

Here is an example:

> Worker 1:
>       Tool 1 - Jobs 1, 2; Tool 2 - Jobs 3, 4
>
> Worker 2:
>       Tool 1 - Jobs 1; Tool 2 - Jobs 3, 4
>
> Worker 3:
>       Tool 2 - Jobs 1, 2, 4
>
> The answer is 4, as all four jobs can be completed by giving Tool 1 to
>   Worker 1 and Tool 2 to Worker 2

From what I can tell, in the case where the tool is omitted and workers can only be assigned to a single job, this problem can be considered equivalent to the assignment problem with uniform cost.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of optimization problem. Or, if its not that complex (I didn't fully get the requirements and problem description), just an ordinary combinatorics problems. Maybe start by explaining the problem in more detail. Make more examples, illustrate it and elaborate on it. Also, share the results of your own research.

Comment: @Zabuza I've edited the OP with a clearer example. Thanks!

Comment: I think the "workers" are just a (deliberate or unintentional) confusion to the problem. Hint: make a rectangular matrix Tool vs. Job and put in a marking ("yes" or "doable") where a worker can do the job with the respective tool.

Comment: Maybe I don't see something, but isn't this a Linear Programming problem with 2 dimensions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming